# задать цвет для mix-blend-mode

Tags: css, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такая верстка
Использую свойство mix-blend-mode для того, чтобы изменять цвет текста на пересечении блоков.

https://codepen.io/jurij-kotowskij/pen/RwNPQZR

```css
.teaser {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color:#d1d3d4;
}
.teaser:before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px;
  bottom: -150px;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.teaser:before {
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #688073;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.teaser:hover:before {
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser">
 <p>Deleniti atque error quidem eaque eligendi ad, pariatur minima quisquam omnis veniam, sint voluptas, a ipsam illum debitis. Voluptatem esse, consectetur qui.
  </p>
</div>
```

Вопрос, как сделать цвет текста на пересечении блоков черным? Не меняя серых и зеленых цветов. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #d1d3d4;
}

div::after {
  content: "Deleniti atque error quidem eaque eligendi ad, pariatur minima quisquam omnis veniam, sint voluptas, a ipsam illum debitis. Voluptatem esse, consectetur qui.";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: black;
  background-color: #688073;
  clip-path: circle(45.0% at 100% 100%);
  transition: 1s;
}

div:hover::after {
  clip-path: circle(100.0% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Deleniti atque error quidem eaque eligendi ad, pariatur minima quisquam omnis veniam, sint voluptas, a ipsam illum debitis. Voluptatem esse, consectetur qui.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: ого, офигенное решение, спасибо!